# How to use insert asynchronously into Cassandra with Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-cassandra

In the older version of Spring Data Cassandra, batching was achieved as below:

```
String cqlIngest = "insert into person (id, name, age) values (?, ?, ?)";

List<Object> person1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
person1.add("10000");
person1.add("David");
person1.add(40);

List<Object> person2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
person2.add("10001");
person2.add("Roger");
person2.add(65);

List<List<?>> people = new ArrayList<List<?>>();
people.add(person1);
people.add(person2);

cassandraOperations.ingest(cqlIngest, people);
```

And in latest version document; https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods
batchOps is introduced on the CQLTemplate which gets CassandraBatchOperations. But this class seems to be entity aware as below

```
template.batchOps().insert(new User()).execute();
```

Is there a way to pass in cqlIngest and people like in older version of code sample given on top?

I'm using Spring 2.0.7.RELEASE with Cassandra driver 3.5.0.

Comment: In your example, you're batching on different partition keys (as I understand the code). This is bad practice - 2 async calls should be faster to execute

Comment: Yes Alex, that's correct. Above was just an example I picked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Spring Data for Apache Cassandra 2.0, the API was refactored and cleaned up.

Previously, the Template API was a mix of low- and high-level functionality with synchronous and asynchronous execution models mashed into a single class.

Since version 2.0, there are now following API's available:

- [CqlTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/CqlTemplate.html)
- [AsyncCqlTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/AsyncCqlTemplate.html)
- [ReactiveCqlTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/ReactiveCqlTemplate.html)
- [CassandraTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraTemplate.html)
- [AsyncCassandraTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/AsyncCassandraTemplate.html)
- [ReactiveCassandraTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/ReactiveCassandraTemplate.html)

The former `ingest` method accepted a CQL string and a `List` of `List` of arguments. We simplified this case as `ingest` executed the CQL asynchronously without proper synchronization. You can achieve a similar functionality through `AsyncCqlTemplate.execute(…)`:

```
ListenableFuture<Boolean> insert1 = template.execute("insert into person (id, name, age) values (?, ?, ?)", 
                                                     "10000", "David", 40);
ListenableFuture<Boolean> insert2 = template.execute("insert into person (id, name, age) values (?, ?, ?)", 
                                                     "10001", "Roger", 65);
```

There are two differences:

1. You are in charge of iterating over the arguments
2. You receive a `ListenableFuture` that allows you to synchronize for successful and exceptional execution.

Comment: Thanks on the reply. I will try this out.

Comment: I kind of feel above approach can be simplified as we need to iterate over Futures. In this case, Im using the same insert query, but the insertion values changes for each insert query. How best can this be achieved.

Comment: Also i made this to run parallely, ended up seeing exception. Pasting code in the answer section

Comment: Can you please let me know what is wrong in the way I have implemented in above section?